# how to create RSA object from private key string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

I have private key stored in string variable and I wanna create RSA object to use SignData() method.

```
string privateKey= "privateKeyFromCertificate";
// some code which generates rsa object from privateKey variable
rsa.SignData();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can:

```
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(yourKeyInBytes);
//Now you have your key in the rsa object
```

Comment: it throws an exception : System.Formats.Asn1.AsnContentException: The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '13', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '16'.

Comment: What is the format of your private key?